# Cannot copy files from local file system to hadoop/hdfs on cloudera

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh, fedora-25

After installing cloudera HDC on fedora25 , I can create folders, but not files nor can I copy data from my local file system to HDFS.

This is the command I use:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/mohammed/Documents/bbc.txt /kareem/corpora/
```

and this is what I get from the terminal:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
copyFromLocal: '/home/mohammed/Documents/bbc.txt': No such file or directory
```

How to overcome this problem?

Your kind help is highly appreciated!

Comment: does `/home/mohammed/Documents/bbc.txt` file exists and have access to hdfs user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your local path of `/home/mohammed` is not accessible as the user `hdfs` you're sudo-ing as to run the whole command. Since the local linux user of `hdfs` cannot enter `/home/mohammed`, the command throws a `No such file or directory` error and exits as a result of being unable to locate or read the provided file.

In most packaged HDFS installations, the `hdfs` user is typically the super-user of the distributed filesystem and administrative commands are typically run as that user. However, doing work over data can and should be done as regular users after using the `hdfs` user to provision permissions and ownerships for regular users.

For your case, you can do the following as your `mohammed` user, if this account also has sudo privileges:

```
# Superuser-provisioning part (do once)

# Ensure the HDFS directory exists by creating it as a superuser
~> sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir -p /kareem/corpora
# Ensure also the HDFS-home path exists by creating it as a superuser
~> sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/mohammed
# Grant ownership entirely to user mohammed for both paths
~> sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown -R mohammed:mohammed /kareem /user/mohammed

# Final usage part (continue or repeat as many times) without superuser

# Upload the local file (note the absence of sudo)
~> hadoop fs -copyFromLocal -f /home/mohammed/Documents/bbc.txt /kareem/corpora/
# Now read it, etc., all done as the regular non-'hdfs' user
~> hadoop fs -text /home/mohammed/Documents/bbc.txt
```